Is this a typo in n-step tree backup section in Sutton-Barto?
Sutton-Barto, page 153.

Should not it be $t<T-n$ in Eq.16? The reason is we have $t<T-1$ and $t<T-2$ for the 1 and 2 step returns, respectively.
